# Receiving unsupported operand error while comparing random number and user input.

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

When I am trying to substract a random number generated using randint function from a number entered by user, I am receiving below error.

Hope someone call help me.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vishal.mohan.gada\Documents\GIt\PythonLearning\Class\exercise9.py", line 5, in 
    if(rannum-input==0):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'

My Code:

```
import random
rannum=random.randint(1,9)
print(rannum)
inputUser=int(input("Please guess one number between 1 to 10: "))
if(rannum-input==0):
    print("Your Guess was right! Congratulations")
elif(rannum-input<0):
    print("Your guess was high")
else:
    print("Your guess was low")
```

Comment: `if(rannum-inputUser==0):`

Comment: @vishalmgada input is a function in python, you are subtracting  input function from rannum which will raise  the  "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'"

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked the variable name and could not recognise the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable name is incorrect. It should be `rannum-inputUser` and not `rannum-input`.

Answer (score 0):

`if(rannum-input==0):` `elif(rannum-input<0):` are using `input`, the identifier of the built-in function, instead of `inputUser`, thevariable which contains the inserted data. Replacing them seems to fix the issue:

```
import random
rannum=random.randint(1,9)
print(rannum)
inputUser=int(input("Please guess one number between 1 to 10: "))
if(rannum-inputUser==0):
    print("Your Guess was right! Congratulations")
elif(rannum-inputUser<0):
    print("Your guess was high")
else:
    print("Your guess was low")
```

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked the variable and could not recognize the error. Thanks for helping.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves your question, you may consider accepting an answer or leave some votes, as reported in [the stackoverflow help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)